# Handling BLOBs in Entity Framework 4.0 in a stream-fashion

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, stream, blob, binary-data

Is it possible to handle (read and write) binary data to SQL Server using Entity Framework 4.0 using streams? (i.e.: not the whole content shipped in a byte array)

An example could be taken from [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/) which illustrates the way to stream nicely data from SQL Server in an example available for ASP.NET MVC. However it requires direct access to the DB and I am curious whether this could be done using an ORM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in Entity Framework 4. You'll need to work directly with the database.

I can't see it happening anytime soon either, since an ORM that didn't materialise objects fully in memory would have a lot of complications.

James

Comment: If I am using Oracle 11g Client and Entity framework v4.0.30319, is there any issue to deal with in this case ?

What about if we use Entity SQL ?